# Text and Image dependent on each other and change every 6 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible to change text after 6 second and in the mean time 2 image will also be change with 3 second delay and text and images should be dependent on each other.
for example:

```
text = [string1, string2]
images = [image1, image2, image3, image4]
```

so if  "string1" change in 6 second so in same 6 second images "image1, image2" will also change. and so same for "string2" images "image3, image4" will change accordingly and main thing is no matter page loading took time due to heavy but text and images iteration should be matched

```
<script>
var text = [string1, string2];
var backgroundImg=[image1, image2, image3, image4];
var counter = 0;
var currentPos = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("animated-text");
var elembg = document.getElementById("animated-background");
var inst = setInterval(change, 6000);
//var bginst = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
console.log("changetextbefore");

function change() {
console.log("changetextbefore call function" + counter + currentPos);

    if (counter == 0 ) {
    console.log("counter == 0 " + counter + text[counter]);
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        office1();  
    }   
    else  {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        console.log("counter == 1" + counter + text[counter]);
        office2();

    }

  counter++;
  
  if (counter >= text.length) {
  console.log("counter >= text.length");
    counter = 0;
    // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
  }
}


(function office1(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hello'); //  your code here  
    
    if (--i) myLoop(i);   //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
  }, 3000)
})(2);      

function office1() {  
    console.log("changetextbefore call office 1");
    
    while (currentPos < 2) {
    console.log("currentPos < 2" + currentPos);
        setInterval(function(){elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[currentPos]+"')" }, 3000);
        console.log(backgroundImg[currentPos]);
        currentPos++;
    }   
    
}  

function office2() {
    console.log("changetextbefore call office 2");
    
    while (currentPos < 4) {
    console.log("currentPos < 4" + currentPos);
        setInterval(function(){elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[currentPos]+"')" }, 3000);
        console.log(backgroundImg[currentPos]);
        currentPos++;
    }
    
    if ( currentPos > 3) {
        console.log("changetextbefore call office 2 if condition");
        currentPos = 0;
    }
}  
</script>
```

Here above i write my code but unfortunately that give not same result expected.  Again i need to change text in 6 second and in same 6 second, two i images will be change image1, image2
and in other 6 second second string will come up and their image3 and image 4  after 3 second delay

```
6second = change text to string1 +  (image1  => 3second , image2  => 3second  )
```

please check here my code in jsfiddle and should see their console

[Run On Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahsan300m/grysL3x4/10/)

Comment: It will be better to add js fiddle code, That will help in answering.

Comment: I meant, code snippet which can be run from the question.

Comment: Click the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet. You can certainly reduce your code to what switches the text and images.

Comment: If they need to change at the same time, then have a *single* loop which changes both at the same time but the text only every other time.

Comment: Use the MOD operator rather than resetting counter to 0

Comment: I add js fiddle as an example, please check

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small code example. adjust interval time by your own for better understanding I have increased the interval time here

```js
let text = ["string1", "string2"];
let backgroundImg = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"];
let counter = 0;
let currentPos = 0;
let elem = document.getElementById("animated-text");
let elembg = document.getElementById("animated-background");

elem.innerText = text[0]

setInterval(() => {
  if (elem.innerText == text[1]) {
    elembg.innerHTML = `<img src="${backgroundImg[2]}.png" />`
  } else {
    elembg.innerHTML = `<img src="${backgroundImg[3]}.png" />`
  }
}, 5000);

setInterval(() => {
  if (elem.innerText == text[0]) {
    elem.innerText = text[1]
    elembg.innerHTML = `<img src="${backgroundImg[1]}.png" />`
  } else {
    elem.innerText = text[0]
    elembg.innerHTML = `<img src="${backgroundImg[0]}.png" />`
  }
}, 10000);
```

You can see the entire code from here:
[Source Code](https://replit.com/@BugsFounder/Text-and-Image-dependent-on-each-other#index.html)

Comment: Hi #Bugs Founder, Thank you so much, I tried your code but still not getting result that we want.

Comment: what you really want can you explain me!!

Comment: 1- First  of all your code is changing image in <img> tag but we are changing image as background image. 
2- Indexing is not matching and even not calling 3rd and 4th image i change some in your code please check is something wrong?
https://replit.com/@AhsanRamzan/Text-Image-dependent?v=1

Comment: https://replit.com/@BugsFounder/Text-Image-dependent#script.js check this. what i suggest you to do download images and use not use directly URLs your images are not valid try to open the URLs in browser you are going to see ```page Is not found``` so download images first and then use it or if you have to use apis then check the API first

Comment: Thanks, 
I check your [code here](https://replit.com/@BugsFounder/Text-Image-dependent#script.js), but its also even not text dependent, text are not matching according to index wise. as image[0], image[1] relate to text[0] and image[1], image[2] relate to text[2]

Comment: I suggest you first learn to code,  I provided you an example with source code you have to modify it as your requirements I don't know what you really want to customize code as you want logic matters depending on which image I am not focused on this part text is not depending on 1 it is depending on 2 then change the code naa why you are talking like a noob bro

Answer (score 0):

I have again written a small code example. adjust interval time and images by your own for better understanding I have increased the interval time here

```js
let text = ["Headquarter - Corso Venezia 35, Milano", "Concept Store Agency - Corso XXII Marzo 29, Milano"];
let backgroundImg = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png"];
let elem = document.getElementById("animated-text");
let elembg = document.getElementById("animated-background");

elem.innerText = text[0]

setInterval(() => {
  if (elem.innerText == text[1]) {
    elembg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${backgroundImg[0]})`
  } else {
    elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImg[1] + ")"
  }
}, 5000);

setInterval(() => {
  if (elem.innerText == text[0]) {
    elem.innerText = text[1]
    elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImg[2] + ")"
  } else {
    elem.innerText = text[0]
    elembg.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgroundImg[3] + ")"
  }
}, 10000);
```

[You can see the entire code from here:](https://replit.com/@BugsFounder/Text-Image-dependent#script.js)